# Parse http request --> run task in background --> when task is finished return response

Tags: c, nginx

As title says, I'm developing http handler module for nginx in which I want to parse http request, run task in background and when it finishes, I want to return response.

I tried having http content handler which uses thread pool to run task. While parsing request I incremented r->main->count and decremented it in task completion handler. Also, in task completion handler I call ngx_http_send_header and ngx_http_output_filter to return result. This works for 10ish requests and then nginx is blocked. It doesnt process http requests anymore.(nothing in logs). In my dev environment, for easier debugging, I'm running nginx with deamon off, master process off and only one worker process.

I also tried attaching my handler in PREACCESS and REWRITE PHASE and then return NGX_DONE when spawning thread, in hope that nginx will call my handler again, but it never does.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_image_render_handler(ngx_http_request_t *r)
{
    ngx_http_image_render_ctx_t   *ctx;
    ngx_http_image_render_loc_conf_t  *plcf;

    plcf = (ngx_http_image_render_loc_conf_t*)ngx_http_get_module_loc_conf(r, ngx_http_image_render_module);

    ctx = (ngx_http_image_render_ctx_t*)ngx_http_get_module_ctx(r, ngx_http_image_render_module);

    if(ctx != NULL)
    {
        if(ctx->done != 1)
        {
            ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log, 0, "ctx already here! AGAIN");
            return NGX_DONE;
        }

        return send_image(ctx->image_render_ctx);
    }

    ctx = (ngx_http_image_render_ctx_t*)ngx_pcalloc(r->pool, sizeof(ngx_http_image_render_ctx_t));
    if (ctx == NULL) {
        ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log, 0, "NGX_HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR");
        return NGX_HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
    ctx->request = r;
    ctx->done = 0;

    ngx_http_set_ctx(r, ctx, ngx_http_image_render_module);

    image_render_ctx_t    *image_render_ctx;
    ngx_thread_task_t  *task;

    task = ngx_thread_task_alloc(r->pool, sizeof(image_render_ctx_t));
    if (task == NULL) {
        return NGX_ERROR;
    }

    image_render_ctx = (image_render_ctx_t*)task->ctx;

    ctx->image_render_ctx = image_render_ctx;

    if(ngx_http_parse_image_request(r, image_render_ctx) != NGX_OK )
    {
        ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log, 0, "error parsing request");
        return NGX_ERROR;
    }

    image_render_ctx->db_util = plcf->db_util;


    task->handler = image_render_func;
    task->event.handler = image_render_completion;
    task->event.data = image_render_ctx;

    if (ngx_thread_task_post((ngx_thread_pool_t*)plcf->pool, task) != NGX_OK) {
        ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log, 0, "error posting to pool");
        return NGX_ERROR;
    }

    r->main->count++;

    ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, r->connection->log, 0, "RECEIVED REQUEST!");

  return NGX_DONE;
}

static int send_image(image_render_ctx_t* trc)
{
    ngx_buf_t    *b;
    ngx_chain_t   out;

    u_char* image = (u_char*)trc->image_data.data();
    size_t image_size = trc->image_data.length();


    ngx_http_request_t *r = trc->r;

    b = ngx_create_temp_buf(r->pool, image_size);

    out.buf = b;
    out.next = NULL;

    ngx_memcpy(b->pos, image, image_size);

    b->last = b->pos + image_size;
    b->memory = 1;
    b->last_buf = 1;


    r->main->count--;

    r->headers_out.content_type.len = sizeof("image/png") - 1;
    r->headers_out.content_type.data = (u_char *) "image/png";

    r->headers_out.status = NGX_HTTP_OK;
    r->headers_out.content_length_n = image_size;

    ngx_http_send_header(r);

    return ngx_http_output_filter(r, &out);;
}

//Attach our handler
static ngx_int_t ngx_http_image_render_init(ngx_conf_t *cf)
{
    ngx_http_handler_pt        *h;
    ngx_http_core_main_conf_t  *cmcf;

    cmcf = (ngx_http_core_main_conf_t*)ngx_http_conf_get_module_main_conf(cf, ngx_http_core_module);

    h = (ngx_http_handler_pt*)ngx_array_push(&cmcf->phases[NGX_HTTP_PREACCESS_PHASE].handlers);
    if (h == NULL) {
        return NGX_ERROR;
    }

    *h = (ngx_http_handler_pt)ngx_http_image_render_handler;

    return NGX_OK;
}

static void
image_render_completion(ngx_event_t *ev)
{
    image_render_ctx_t *ctx = (image_render_ctx_t*)ev->data;

    ngx_log_error(NGX_LOG_ERR, ctx->r->connection->log, 0, "sending back image!!!");

    ngx_http_image_render_ctx_t   *rctx;
    rctx = (ngx_http_image_render_ctx_t*)ngx_http_get_module_ctx(ctx->r, ngx_http_image_render_module);

    rctx->done = 1;
}
```

Comment: Without code for context this is really way too vague a question to even begin to answer. What handler? Attached how? We need specifics.

Comment: Sorry about confusion. In short this what I need to do: parse uri and args from incoming http request, run task in background(I'm using nginx's threadpool) and return task result as response. I started by creating simple HTTP handler module(aka content handler), where instead of returning response in it I did it in task completion handler with problems I described in my post.

Comment: Code attached with attempt to attach my handler to PREACCESS phase.

Comment: You may need to find a way to debug this better, to dig in deeper to see where you might be jamming up the nginx process. It's hard to say based on this code, but having code is a huge improvement.

Comment: In content handler implementation where my nginx stops processing requests, it's blocked on epoll_wait which is "normal"? I made QT Creator project and I'm using it for dev and debugging.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting project, but I'm not sure Stack Overflow can really help here as this seems like a pretty nuanced problem that's not trivial to reproduce with your code sample given.